# Unable to install Firebug and FirePath despite looking for suggestions

Tags: selenium, xpath, firebug, firepath

I believe the default Selenium web browser is Firefox. My professor asked me to operate Selenium with Firefox version 43.0.1. Above it doesn't work, tested! However the issue is, I installed the latest version of Firebug and FirePath to get the XPaths. But it doesn't seem to work. Please help. I have read the earlier posts on a related topic in StackOverflow, still not working.

Comment: How is going? Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Firebug is [officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com/). Though you don't need Firebug or FirePath to use Selenium.

Selenium also works with CSS selectors. Or, if you really need XPaths, you can copy them using the Firefox DevTools' Inspector.

[image: Copy XPath in Firefox DevTools]